# Почему нужно поставить тире?

Tags: пунктуация

«Хочешь — поиграем.»

Я знаю, что здесь нужно тире. Но как правильно объяснить, почему так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> § 172. Тире ставится между двумя предложениями, если они связаны по
>   смыслу как придаточное (на первом месте) с главным (на втором месте),
>   но подчинительные союзы отсутствуют, например:
>
> ```
> Назвался груздем – полезай в кузов.
>
> Лес рубят – щепки летят.
>
> Сам запутался – сам и распутывайся; умел кашу заварить – умей ее 
> расхлебывать; любишь кататься – люби и саночки возить.
> Салтыков-Щедрин
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Здесь следствие. Тире ставится, если есть причинно-следственные отношения между частями. Желание - причина, а действие - следствие.

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151):

> Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если в ней содержится следствие, результат либо вывод из того, о чем говорится в первой части.
>   Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если в первой части обозначается условие совершения действия, о котором говорится во второй части (в начале первой части можно добавить союз *если*):

*(Если) хочешь - поиграем.*

Народный пример:
*Сделал дело - гуляй смело.*

Ещё одна причина - пропуск подлежащего. Полный вариант:
*Если хочешь, то **мы** поиграем.*

Но в вопросительном предложении будет запятая:
*Хочешь, поиграем?*